# Plo 2D of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I´ve got a big Matrix, it is an Array of  856 x 883, and I would like to plot the values of the Matrix in a 2D plot. 
Since I'm new in Python I don't know which libraries do I have to use and how to use them.

I would be thankful if you could explain this to me.

Best regards.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html

Comment: because you don't say what kind plot you want, best answer is that Nihal's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use the matplotlib.pyplot `imshow`. Just define the array and pass it to plot. see a mockup below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
MyArray=np.random.random((856,883))#an Array of 856 x 883
plt.imshow(MyArray);
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Result below:

[image]